# 'Click' event not working within typescript/angular after appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

if (CSV == '') { alert("Invalid data"); return; }

```
  const uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = uri;
  link.download = "Payments.csv";
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
```

When i am tryinng to download the file, " link.click "  is not firing not getting any console errors.

Answer (score 1):

This line has an issues

```
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

You can remove it and add the below code for hiding your link from the document

```
link.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
```

**Complete snippet code**

```
const uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
const a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.href = uri;
a.download = "Payments.csv";
a.target = 'blank';
a.click();
```

I hope you will be clear with this info

Comment: After the code is updated. I am getting a look like a console warning like " Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set. "

Comment: You able to download file even you getting warning in console?

Comment: no I am unable to download file

Comment: Include `sandbox=allow-download` in your iFrame tag

Comment: I Can Download thank You